# Сделать из прямоугольного изображение круглое в css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Дано прямоугольное изображение в макете, которое необходимо сделать круглым.
Обернул в див, обрезал края, но подвинуть, как на макете, не выходит..Проблема со сдвигом изображение в этом кругу. Может есть фича на Бутстрап какая, мало ли..

```css
.item {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.photo {
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.personPhoto {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
  <div class="photo">
    <img class="personPhoto" alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvTnQ10XsARegWrtgIwH8LiUMMNeggR5CDtHdVDUPFZwdTA-En">
  </div>
</article>
```

[image: на макете..]

[image: исходящее]

Comment: А как на макете?

Comment: @br3t добавлял, но куда-то делись... отредактировал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Закругляем `div`-обертку, а не изображение
2. Выставляем `width:auto` у изображения для сохранения пропорций.

```css
.item {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.photo {
  width: 132px;
  height: 132px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.personPhoto {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
  <div class="photo">
    <img class="personPhoto" alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvTnQ10XsARegWrtgIwH8LiUMMNeggR5CDtHdVDUPFZwdTA-En">
  </div>
</article>
```